# How to quickly deconstruct javascript objects in pycharm

Tags: vue.js, pycharm, vue-composition-api

I've recently started writing a Vue.js using the composition API and script setup. I'm also using Pinia for state management.

In general, I enjoy less boilerplate, but the thing that has me frustrated is object deconstruction.

In general, I think deconstructing objects makes for more beautiful code, but I find it excruciatingly slow to write because I feel like I have to essentially write backwards.

Here is an example of the same code written normally and with deconstruction:

```
const { attribute } = object; // Example 1
const attribute = object.attribute; // Example 2
```

Now in example two, when I write the code, everything flows logically from left to write when writing the code. When I get to the expression and press '.', my editor (pycharm) will give me suggestions on what to write, and I can quickly move forward and write the rest of my code.

However, if I want to write Example 1, I first write 'const', then add the curly brackets, and then comes the problem. "What the hell is the name of the attribute inside my object?". I won't get help from my editor because it doesn't yet know which object I'm trying to deconstruct. Ok, so now I write the rest of the expression first so:

```
const { } = object;
```

My cursor is now at the end of the line, so I have to go back to inside the curly brackets, and then my editor will again offer me some assistance, and I can move on.

In summary, I find this really slow but I figured I couldn't be the only one with this problem. So the question is, how can you write deconstruction fast in modern editors (preferably pycharm)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding an answer right after posting this. So the solution I found was creating a live template called 'deconstruct' in pycharm that looks like this:

```
const {$variable$} = $object$
```

And setting the order of the variables to first go to $object$, then to $variables$, and then to the end of the line.

Now deconstructing is as fast as the *uglier* normal way :)